# Listing number of files inside a large collection of sub folders

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I have a single folder with over 2000 subfolders inside.

Each subfolder has a collection of different files inside.

How can I list the number of files inside each subfolder?

Ideally something like this:

```
\folder\sub-folder-482 : 14 files.
\folder\sub-folder-483 : 2 files.
\folder\sub-folder-484 : 107 files.
```

Outputting the results as a CSV file would be preferable, but I am open to any solutions that don't require downloading additional software.

I have already got DU from SysInternals, does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody panic, I figured it out myself...

```
du64 -c -l 2 > filelist.csv
```

`du64` is the 64-Bit version of `du` - [Disk Utilities from SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/du.aspx)

Comment: * not that anybody was panicking of course